# Help finding good deep mathematics problems

Tags: problem-solving

Once, when I Was doing calculus 2, someone challenged me to calculate and prove the Gaussian integral, with a few hints, and a few days, I managed to.
It was a great feeling to solve a “deep” multi step long  math problem.
My question:
Do any of you know of resources for problems of this kind?
I’m looking for an online resource, in the level of calculus 2.
As a person planning on being a pure mathematician, I know that I will be presented with a problem and I will need to find an approach to solve it, most calculus textbooks provide a step by step explanation on the problem, detailing someone else’s reasoning.
When I see someone else’s reasoning it makes sense but I always wondered if I was presented with the problem what I would have done.

Comment: Since you are already MSE user, I really think that it is a very good source of quite deep problems.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici - How do you filter the good questions out from all the noise though?

Comment: What do you mean by "deep" in that context?

Comment: I'm a fan of problems on brilliant.org and artofproblemsolving.com, but I don't think this is a full answer so I'm leaving it as a comment. Another great source of questions, though perhaps not 'deep' in the sense that they require lots of calculation but 'deep' in the sense that they require good reasoning, includes the good questions project: http://pi.math.cornell.edu/~GoodQuestions/materials.html

Comment: @CarlosTorres , deep in the sense of having many steps and being interesting and requiring a surprising approach .

Comment: As these are surely known to you — [**Calculus**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0914098918) by Spivak, [**Introduction to Calculus and Analysis**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/354065058X) by Courant/John, and [**A Course of Pure Mathematics**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0521092272) by Hardy — perhaps you could indicate in what ways none of these has what you want ([especially Courant/John](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/79994/13130)), since each has many problems that appear to be what you're looking for. See also the books listed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/766183/13130).

Comment: Could you revise your last sentence of the 3rd edit for clarity? As presently written there appears to be a nested collection of (or a sequence of) "if ... then" statements that is very unclear.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro, is it better now?

Comment: Yes, it's much better. I did not even know what you intended to say in the previous version, but now I do, and what you say in that last sentence also provides more context to your question. You might want to try googling "calculus" (also "honors calculus" or "advanced calculus") along with each of the phrases (used in separate searches with the "calculus" phrase you're using) "Moore method", "inquiry-based learning", "student centered learning", "active learning".

Answer (score 2):

razivio, look at Joseph Edwards Treatise on Integral Calculus froim 1920 (can find pdf on the web).  Full of challenge problems from Cambridge Tripos exams.  (Warning, stay in the earlier part of the text as that is calc 2.  But he also has calc 3 and really complex analysis in there also.)

Comment: Thanks, the book is interesting and provides good explanations (from what I read) but it doesn’t provide the problems I’m looking for, thanks for recommending it though.